# PrimeFaces 8 - Lazy p:dataScroller - issue with Drag and Drop

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2, drag-and-drop

We use a `p:dataScroller` with a `LazyDataModel` to display products that can be dragged from lazy loaded search results and dropped into a shopping cart.

When more than one chunk of results have been loaded, we are only able to drag/drop items from the most recent chunk of data. If I try to drop an item from the first chunk into my cart, it will incorrectly drop the corresponding item from the most recently loaded chunk in stead.

**Example:** After the DataScroller has performed 3 lazy loads (3 chunks displayed), if I try to drop the 5th item from the first or second chunk of results, the 5th item from the 3rd chunk of results will be returned by the `DragDropEvent.getData()` method.

Our Facelets template looks something like this. The *droppable* element is the sticky header, which is a div with id = *headerPanel*.

```
  <h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">
      <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" life="2000">
        <p:autoUpdate />
      </p:growl> 
      <h:panelGroup id="headerPanel" layout="block" styleClass="header">
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/layout/Header.xhtml" />
      </h:panelGroup>
      <p:droppable for="headerPanel" 
                   scope="shoppingCartAdd" 
                   datasource="productScroller" 
                   hoverStyleClass="dragActive"
                   tolerance="touch">
        <p:ajax listener="#{shoppingCart.addProductToShoppingCart}" 
                update="shoppingCartButton shoppingCartSidebar" />
      </p:droppable>
      <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/layout/ShoppingCartBar.xhtml" />
      <h:panelGroup id="contentPanel" layout="block" styleClass="content">
        <ui:insert name="contentPanel">Content</ui:insert>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
```

The `p:draggable` elements are inside a `p:dataScroller` in a ui-composition that defines the *contentPanel* from our Facelets template:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/Layout.xhtml">

  <ui:param name="title" value="Product Search" />

  <ui:define name="contentPanel">
      <p:commandButton id="submitButton" 
                       action="#{productSearchBean.searchAction}" 
                       ajax="false" 
                       value="Find All Products" />
      <h:panelGrid id="resultsGrid" styleClass="resultsGrid">
        <p:dataScroller id="productScroller" 
                        buffer="5"
                        chunkSize="10" 
                        lazy="true"
                        rendered="#{productSearchBean.productList.rowCount > 0}"
                        rowIndexVar="resultIndex"
                        styleClass="scroller"
                        value="#{productSearchBean.productList}" 
                        var="rowProduct">
          <p:panel id="searchResultsPanel" 
                   header="#{resultIndex + 1} - Product ##{rowProduct.productId}" 
                   closable="true" 
                   toggleable="true" 
                   styleClass="searchResultsPanel">
            <h:panelGrid id="productDataGrid" columns="2" columnClasses="thumbnailPanel, textPanel">
              <h:panelGroup id="imageDiv" layout="block" styleClass="thumbnailContainer">
                <span class="alignmentHelper" />
                <p:graphicImage id="thumbnailImage" styleClass="thumbnailImage" value="#{rowProduct.thumbnailUrl}" />
                <p:draggable for="thumbnailImage" helper="clone" revert="true" scope="shoppingCartAdd" />
              </h:panelGroup>
              <h:panelGrid id="textDataGrid" columns="2" columnClasses="padRight, padLeft">
                <h:outputText value="id:" /> #{rowProduct.productId}<br/>
                <h:outputText value="name:" /> #{rowProduct.productName}<br/>
              </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
          </p:panel>
        </p:dataScroller>
      </h:panelGrid>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Here's the listener method that gets invoked on a drop event. As mentioned above, the `DragDropEvent.getData()` method returns the wrong data item if multiple lazy loads have occurred and the user is trying to drag/drop an item from anything but the most recent chunk of data:

```
  public void addProductToShoppingCart(DragDropEvent shoppingCartDropEvent) {
    Long draggedId = productIdFromDragDrop(shoppingCartDropEvent);
    if (addProductToDefaultShoppingCart(userId, draggedId)) {
      fetchShoppingCartProducts();
      addSuccessMessage(draggedId);
    }
    else {
      addErrorMessage(draggedId);
    }
  }

  private Long productIdFromDragDrop(DragDropEvent productDroppedEvent) {
    Long droppedProductId = null;
    Object dropObj = productDroppedEvent.getData();
    if (dropObj != null && dropObj instanceof ProductView) {
      ProductView view = (ProductView) dropObj;
      droppedProductId = view.getProductId();
    }
    return droppedProductId;
  }
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug where the lazy loading of the scroller is losing track of where it is for Drag and Drop.

Comment: There is this open issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6087